# How to change sessionid value Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

i want to change PHPSESSID name and value. I can could name but i couldn't change value.
i have following stracture. How i change sessionid value.

My module.config.php is

```
return array(
    'session'         => array(
        'config'     => array(
            'class'   => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
            'options' => array(
                'name' => 'portal1'
            ),
        ),
        'storage'    => 'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
                'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

My Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap($e) {
    $this->bootstrapSession($e);
}

public function bootstrapSession($e) {
    $session = $e->getApplication()
            ->getServiceManager()
            ->get('Zend\Session\SessionManager');
    $session->start();

    $container = new Container('initialized');
    if (!isset($container->init)) {
        $session->regenerateId(true);
        $container->init = 1;
    }
}

public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories'  => array(
            'Zend\Session\SessionManager'           => function ($sm) {
                $config = $sm->get('config');
                if (isset($config['session'])) {
                    $session = $config['session'];

                    $sessionConfig = null;
                    if (isset($session['config'])) {
                        $class         = isset($session['config']['class']) ? $session['config']['class']
                            : 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig';
                        $options       =
                            isset($session['config']['options']) ? $session['config']['options'] : array();
                        $sessionConfig = new $class();
                        $sessionConfig->setOptions($options);
                    }

                    $sessionStorage = null;
                    if (isset($session['storage'])) {
                        $class          = $session['storage'];
                        $sessionStorage = new $class();
                    }

                    $sessionSaveHandler = null;
                    if (isset($session['save_handler'])) {
                        $sessionSaveHandler = $sm->get($session['save_handler']);
                    }

                    $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig, $sessionStorage, $sessionSaveHandler);

                    if (isset($session['validator'])) {
                        $chain = $sessionManager->getValidatorChain();
                        foreach ($session['validator'] as $validator) {
                            $validator = new $validator();
                            $chain->attach('session.validate', array($validator, 'isValid'));

                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $sessionManager = new SessionManager();
                }
                Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);

                return $sessionManager;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

MyController.php is; i want to change PHPSESSID key and value here.

```
public function loginAction() {
    $container = new Container();    /*
    i want to change PHPSESSID key and value
    eg: portal1: fafsafg43kgfdsgfds //my sessionid value
    */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I want to clarify something before answer the question -
What dose it means "i want to change PHPSESSID key and value"
As far I understand you want to change the "PHPSESSID" text. that means you want to call it in different name like "MySessionId" isn't it?

Actually I'm not authorized to write comment where I can ask!

Anyway, if you want to call it with different name than its not the issue of ZF its your server's PHP session settings. So, consult the session part of the server. You may get help from http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name OR http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php
And ZF also let you change that name by Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig class or Zend\Session\SessionManager class you have to set the preferred name by calling setName method.

Now if you want to change the value of session id (its automatically generated and save it into PHPSESSID) you may do it in ZF. Here is the code of ZF2 to set the value explicitly

```
$container->getManager()->setId($id); # For current session manager of your container
$container->getDefaultManager()->setId($id); # For default session manager of your entire app
```

In above code $id is the value you want to set.