# How to rename the cookie name from PHPSESSID to SOMEOTHER in Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework

I did already tried approach of zend framework 1. I did place this code of line in my application.ini file which is this

```
resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
resources.session.save_path = "/tmp"
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
resources.session.cookie_httponly = true
resources.session.cookie_secure = On
resources.session.name = "SOMEOTHER"
```

But it does not working still name is showing "PHPSESSID". 
I am attaching a screen shot for your reference.

[image: screenshot which is showing cookie name]
Thanks is advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change sessionid value Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047338/how-to-change-sessionid-value-zend-framework-2)

Comment: No its not I want to change name "PHPSESSIONID" to "SOMEOTHER" not value.

Comment: Look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27519954/1842846) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did resolve this issue

We don't need to do major thing. 
 1. Just Install Zend Session Library in project folder.
 2. Include/Use Installed library (use Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig), Create a function "_initSession" in Zend Bootstrap.php file 
 3. And write this line of code

```
$sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
$sessionConfig->setOptions(array('name' => 'SOMEOTHER'));
```